# Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to specified type 'UInt32'

Tags: swift, option-type, uint32

I'm trying to assign an array count to a UInt32. I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to specified type 'UInt32'". The array count is type Int, but the error says "Int?", which looks like an optional Int. I have no idea what else it could mean.

```
let randColorCount:UInt32 = slider?.randUIColors.count
```

I've also tried:

```
let randColorCount:UInt32 = UInt32(slider?.randUIColors.count)
```

But I get the error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UInt32' with an argument list of type '(Int?)'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`slider?.randUIColors.count` results in `Int?` because of the use of the optional chaining.

One simple solution is to combine this with the nil coalescing operator `??` to provide a default value incase `slider` is `nil`.

```
let randColorCount = UInt32(slider?.randUIColors.count ?? 0)
```